# Only show result when the author has a relation with the current user

Tags: views

You might already suspected it, I'm talking about groups. I've a content type what represents groups, the node/group is referred in a field (`field_group`) on the user entity. With this relation I want to define "permissions" in views.

For example the blog I build now displays content of all groups, no matter what group you are in, the view will always display all blog nodes. Now I want only to display the nodes what have an author with a `field_group` value equal to the currently logged in user its `field_group` value.

How should I do this in views? Some people mentioned to use contextual filters, I tried some common options but it didn't resulted like expected...

Please, let me know if you know a working setup.

Thanks ~ F.

Answer (score 1):

Found out how it should be done if you can refer to an author.

My setup:

1. add relation ship `Content : Author` as "author"
2. add relation ship `User: Group (field_group) - Appears in: user:user.` with the relation to "author".
3. add contextual filter `User: Group (field_group) - Appears in: user:user.` with at "When the filter value is NOT available" -> "Provide default value" -> "PHP Code" the following code:
   `global $user;
   $data = user_load($user->uid, TRUE);
   return $data->field_group['und'][0]['nid'];`